# sqlite vs postgresql - database size comparision

Tags: postgresql, sqlite

I have a sqlite db file which includes 2 tables and each has over 800k records. **the sqlite db file size is 186MB.**

I was planned to migrate those records to postgresql database.
In order to made it, I followed these steps:
1) prepared a view to unify these 2 tables in sqlite (they have relation)
2) create a table with one column type jsonb in postgres
3) made a simple program to read from sqlite and then write to postgresql

all 3 steps worked fine... sadly I didn't get what I expected!
**postgresql table size is 367MB...** 
I thought that was going to be much lesser!

How could that be possible the sqlite tables (800k *2 records) consume less disk space than postgresql with one jsonb column and half record?!

Comment: JSON has a lot of overhead? Comparing the sizes after doing a more literal table per table, row by row migration would be more useful.

Comment: @Shawn every single row is exactly 18 key/value pairs and length is not more than 500 character as string. isn't it surprising that sqlite has 1600k records (combine of 2 tables) consumes less disk spaces than postgresql table with 800k records of single jsonb column?

Comment: No? Different databases, different file formats, the jsonb format presumably trades size for optimized data access times... Tons of factors. Different table schemas just make any comparison even less meaningful.

Comment: Honestly, if nothing else, the jsonb records are including field names, while the table records won't (it's part of the schema info). You seem to be asking "isn't it weird that when I store something in a different system and also a completely different format, that the storage footprint is different?". Well, yeah, of course it's different.